# How to pull artifacts from Artifactory to project classpath using gradle?

Tags: java, groovy, gradle, artifactory

I'm new to gradle and Artifactory integration and so far I can publish artifacts from one workspace to another.

What I did was created a gradle sample project and now I would like to publish i.e. JUnit jar into Artifactory and then retrieve it to my project classpath as a dependency, so that I can run my project.

### Project strructure

[image]

### build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'
   apply plugin: 'eclipse'
   //apply plugin: 'artifactory-publish'
   sourceCompatibility = 1.5
   version = '1.0'

jar 
{
    manifest 
     {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Quickstart', 'Implementation Version': version
    }
}

buildscript 
{
    repositories 
    {
        maven 
        {
            url 'http://dl.bintray.com/jfrog/jfrog-jars' 
        }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies 
    {
        classpath(group: 'org.jfrog.buildinfo', name: 'build-info-extractor-gradle', version: '2.1.0')
    }
}

//pull/retrieve artifacts(jar) from artifactory
repositories 
{
    ivy 
    {
        url = 'http://localhost:8081/artifactory/APM-jars'
         credentials
        {
            username = 'admin'
            password = 'password'
        }
    }
    mavenCentral()

dependencies {
     compile group: 'jakarta-regexp', name: 'jakarta-regexp', version: '1.+'
    compile group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections', version: '3.2'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
}
}
 test {
    systemProperties 'property': 'value'
}

///publish/upload artifact (jar) into 3 different type of builds
uploadArchives 
{
    repositories 
    {
        //Just copy to a directory
    //flatDir 
        //{
            //dirs 'repos2'
        //}


        //Publish to an Ivy repository in Artifactory.
        ivy 
        {    
            url = 'http://localhost:8081/artifactory/test-ivy'
            credentials 
            {
                username = 'admin'
                password = 'password'
            }
        }
    //Publish to a Gradle repository in Artifactory.
    ivy 
    {
        url = 'http://localhost:8081/artifactory/test-gradle'
        credentials 
        {
            username = 'admin'
            password = 'password'
        }
        //layout 'gradle'
        layout 'pattern', 
        {
            artifact '[module]/[revision]/[artifact](.[ext])'
            ivy '[module]/[revision]/ivy.xml'
        }
       }
        //Publish to a Maven repository in Artifactory.
        ivy 
        {
            url = 'http://[host]:port/artifactory/test-maven'
            credentials 
        {
                username = 'admin'
                password = 'password'
            }
            layout 'maven'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't easily publish a third-party Jar with Gradle. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: I haven't used Artifactory, but I would guess that it works in much the same way as in Nexus. That is, you publish your own artifacts there in the build script, while for 3rd party libraries you typically specify 3rd party repositories (Maven central, Bintray JCentral, Sonatype, etc), so that your repository manager (Artifactory/Nexus) knows where to look for artifacts that are not yet cached. In Nexus you can also manually upload artifacts if they are not available in any of the repos you want it to download from. I would be surprised if that's not possible in Artifactory.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser - It doesn't have to be a 3rd party jar, what i'm trying to achieve is to deploy an artifact (jar) onto Artifactory; let's say under ABC repository. So when my project whats an API from that library,the gradle should go and get the dependency from artifactory and place it in for that project.

Comment: OK. So what concrete problem do you have? Have you checked out the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html) and the samples in the full Gradle distribution? The easiest way is to treat Artifactory as a Maven repository, not an Ivy repository.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are only interested in getting resources from artifactory you can leave all the build.gradle-code you get from artifactory and just enter:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'http://artifactory.domain/artifactory/libs-release'
    }
}
```

This approach assumes you have anonymous read access to you artifactory. Otherwise you also need to create the gradle.properties file containing:

```
HOST=localhost
REALM=Artifactory Realm
USER=admin
PASSWORD=password
```

Comment: It was `maven { url 'http://localhost/artifactory/libs-release-local' }` in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You should just use [Artifactory plugin for Gradle](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Gradle+1.6+Publishing+Artifactory+Plugin#Gradle1.6PublishingArtifactoryPlugin-ControllingBuildInfo%27sBuildNameandBuildNumber). It makes both publishing and retrieving a blast, both as Ivy artifacts and/or as Maven artifacts.

Comment: The existence of such thing feels very wrong. From the point of view of the build script it is a maven repository and the fact it is implemented by artifactory should be a technical detail that should have no effect on the script itself. At least not for normal build.

Comment: @JanHudec Maven repository layout is a standard lowest denominator. You can achieve more by using the extra features (like build info metadata and more), or you can use it as it was any other maven repo.